# Javascript - Custom video player which handles buffering and seeking

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to build a custom javascript based video player which handles all of the buffering and seeking. I've looked at the sample [here](http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-custom-html5-video-player-9134473) but it doesn't have any seeking ability and seems to buffer the whole video before it can be played.

I want to be able start playing a video from another source immediately by buffering only a small length of the video(range request). Same goes for seeking, by sending a range request to the video host. All of this has to handled by javascript, not the HTML front end.

Any thoughts and sample code I can get started on? I'm quite new to Javascript.

Comment: buffering and seeking is handled by the `html5` `video` element already, you just need to use you controls to set the `currenttime` property to adjust the playhead (eg based on a click on the timeline). have a look here https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html for events you can/should handle if you are skinning your own player

Comment: Metadata is needed before playback. Make sure your MP4 videos have their metadata (called MOOV) at start of file bytes not at the back end behind all the a/v data (which means it must fully buffer before playback begins). You can use a tool like FFmpeg to move the MOOV atom to front.